# Error Installing libgdal1 Package

Tags: qgis, gdal, boundless-suite, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to install the libgdal1 package on Ubuntu 12.04, but the apt is returing this error:

> dpkg: error processing
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdal1_1.9.1-2~precise4_amd64.deb
>   (--unpack):
>
> libgdal 1.9.1-1 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1.16.1',
>   which is also in package libgdal 1.9.1-1

I believe libgdal 1.9.1-1 is installed from OpenGeo Suite. How can I fix this problem?

QGIS and osm2pgl require the libgdal1 package.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge libgdal && apt-get clean`?

Comment: Might be of interest too http://askubuntu.com/questions/206593/how-to-install-rgdal-on-ubuntu-12-10

Answer (score 3):

I ended not being able to have OpenGeo suite installed.

There was a conflict with the libdal packages between OpenGeo suite, and the libgdal packages of postGIS and QGIS.